# error while loading shared libraries: libPocoNet.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, http, poco-libraries

The below command returns

```
sudo find / -name libPocoNet.so

    /home/sandeep/server2/poco/cmake-build/lib/libPocoNet.so
    /home/sandeep/server/cmake_build/lib/libPocoNet.so
    /home/sandeep/server/poco/cmake_build/lib/libPocoNet.so
    /home/sandeep/server/poco/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoNet.so
    /usr/local/lib/libPocoNet.so
```

to compile code I am using

```
g++ poco.cpp  -lPocoNet
```

while execution

I am getting the error
error while loading shared libraries: libPocoNet.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

how I built the source

```
$ git clone -b master https://github.com/pocoproject/poco.git
$ cd poco
$ mkdir cmake-build
$ cd cmake-build
$ cmake .. && cmake --build .
$ sudo cmake --build . --target install
$ cd ..
$ ./configure
$ make -s -j4
$ cd cmake-build
$ make -s -j4
$ cd ..
$ sudo make install
$ cd cmake-build
$ sudo make install
```

-----------solved using-------------------

```
sandeep@sandeep:~$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
sandeep@sandeep:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sandeep@sandeep:~$ g++ poco.cpp -lPocoNet
sandeep@sandeep:~$ ./a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

if all necessary libs added to your CMakeList.txt just run the below line and run a.out app.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib

Answer (score 0):

I moved all Poco libraries from /usr/local/lib to /usr/lib/, it worked for me.